# Тесты по c++ с объяснениями

Tags: c++, тестирование, синтаксис

Прочитал самоучитель Герберта Шилдта и многих деталей не понял. Может кто-нибудь подсказать какие-нибудь тесты по с++ с объяснениями, чтобы примерно знать свой уровень?

Comment: На мой взгляд, Ваш уровень определяет спектр задач, которые Вы можете решить, а не прохождение тестов. И Ваш спектр задач, уверен, Вы знаете сами :)

Answer (score 0):

На http://muliver.org можно пройти тесты по c++ и после прохождения посмотреть объяснения, правда, там они не для всех вопросов будут.

Answer (score 0):

На [quizful.net](http://www.quizful.net/test) есть ряд весьма неплохих тестов по достаточно большому перечню языков, в том числе и по С++. Более того, тестов по С++ там аж целых 7 штук, большинство вопросов объяснены и сопровождаются комментариями других участников.

Правда, есть и ложка дегтя - после прохождения нескольких тестов вам настойчиво намекнут, что ученье - свет, а за свет надо платить, и тем самым попросят сделать что-нибудь полезное для сервиса - рассказать о нем тысяче друзей, добавить собственный вопрос или даже тест, или банально пожертвовать денежку

Answer (score 0):

А вот появился тест по С++ здесь https://certification.mail.ru/tests/

Можно получить сертификат.

Тест проверяет знание синтаксиса и основных особенностей языка, умение пользоваться структурами данных и алгоритмами стандартной библиотеки. Вопросы теста ориентированы на стандарт языка С++11

Comment: Вопросы теста ориентированы на компиляцию кода в голове на время. Ни больше ни меньше.